# Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to setup a kafka producer with KafkaAvroSerialzer for value. And I am facing this error wheneve rit is trying to created the Producer. I am using all the jars provided in confluent 5.2.1

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:104)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:81)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:53)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:43)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:48)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:370)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
at swing.KafkaUtilityPanel.sendMessage(KafkaUtilityPanel.java:229)
at swing.KafkaUtilityPanel.access$1200(KafkaUtilityPanel.java:32)
at swing.KafkaUtilityPanel$4.actionPerformed(KafkaUtilityPanel.java:164)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**Producer**
This is the producer part I have added and it is failing at trying to create the kafka producer with KafkaAvroSerializer.

```
try {
        //Configure connection properties

        Properties producerConfig = createKafkaProducerProperties(environment);

        //Create Kafka Producer
        try (KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord> myProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig)) {

            //Create ProducerRecord
            Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/main/resources/investorOnboarding.avsc"));
            GenericRecordBuilder genericRecordBuilder = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);

            GenericData.Record genericRecord = genericRecordBuilder.build();

            final ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> myProducerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName.getCode(), genericRecord);

            //Send the message
            myProducer.send(myProducerRecord, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
                    if(exception == null){
                        alertSuccessStatus("Message has been successfully sent to Kafka");
                    }
                }
            });

            //Disconnect
            myProducer.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info(ex.getMessage());
    }
}



private Properties createKafkaProducerProperties(Environment implementation) throws UnknownHostException, PasswordProviderException {

    Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
    producerConfig.put("client.id", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    producerConfig.put("bootstrap.servers", implementation.getBootStrapServers());
    producerConfig.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    producerConfig.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
    producerConfig.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8085");
```

**Jars Added**

[image: Jars added to the Intellij project libraries]

Comment: Can you share the code you've written for your producer?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I have added the producer code as well

Comment: @cricket_007 do you have any clue on this on what I might be missing out ?

Comment: Show your POM or Gradle? Make sure you're using Java 8?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "using all jars" because there's actually a lot of those, and you certainly don't need them all

Comment: Yeah I am using java 8, yup by all jars I meant the ones required for the generic producer to start of.

Comment: Why are you not using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: @cricket_007 It was not resolving the dependencies from io.confluent when added to pom, I guess  some changes are required for that on settings. I was just creating a dummy utility so just went with adding them as libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `kafka-schema-registry-client`, and I don't think you need `kafka-schema-registry`.

In any case, I'd strongly recommend you use Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies for any Java project

https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/install.html#installation-maven

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, started of from scratch itself resolving the dependencies from maven. It is working now.