# Cannot create producer with FlinkKafkaProducer in version 1.8.* with Kafka 5.2.*

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

The Apache Flink Kafka Producer creation fails when using flink 1.8.*.

The same thing works with flink version less than 1.8.* such as 1.7.*.
The following error message is displayed.

The producer looks likes this,

```
new FlinkKafkaProducer(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), kafkaConnectionProperties);
```

error logs attached below

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:457)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:304)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.createProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:889)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:960)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initNonTransactionalProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:956)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.beginTransactionInternal(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:382)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.initializeState(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:373)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initializeState(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:859)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(Ljava/util/List;ILjava/util/Map;)V
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:43)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.configure(ExtendedSerializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:372)
    ... 18 more
```

Configuration added below

```
ext {
    javaVersion = '1.8'
    flinkVersion = '1.8.1'
    scalaBinaryVersion = '2.12'
    confluentVersion = '5.2.2'
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-java:${flinkVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
    compile group: "org.apache.flink", name: "flink-connector-kafka_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: flinkVersion
    compile group: "org.apache.flink", name: "flink-avro-confluent-registry", version: flinkVersion
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.flink:flink-table-planner_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
    compile group: "org.apache.flink", name: "flink-statebackend-rocksdb_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: flinkVersion
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: confluentVersion
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have the wrong version of some dependency? Maybe share your build configuration file.

Comment: added to the content

Comment: Please check the answer in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514984/could-not-initialize-class-io-confluent-kafka-schemaregistry-client-rest-restser. Possibly could resolve your problem